# "We eat when I say we eat!"

Tags: grammar, future, when

"Quiet! We eat when I say we eat!"
"OK, we wait for your say-so."

> Why can we omit the first "will" in sentences such as:

"We will eat when I say so!"
"We will eat, when I say 'we eat'!"
"We will eat when I say we will eat!"
?

- What do we call this?
- Does it change the meaning?
- Are both correct?
- Are there examples in which one can be used, while the other cannot?

I search and see several examples of this in books and movie quotes.

Comment: Related, [Which is correct: “when you have finished” or “when you will finish”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6213/which-is-correct-when-you-have-finished-or-when-you-will-finish).

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["When X is" or "When X will be"?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/22752/when-x-is-or-when-x-will-be)

Comment: I have edited the question because my intent had been to ask about the first "will" and not to even include the second. I'll also now read the possible duplicates linked.

Comment: It's that way because Mom's in charge.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I perceive

> We eat when I say we eat !

As a general "rule" set up by the person, which does not not necessarily apply only to the near future. It conveys a sense of *"I'm the boss and we do things when I say we do !"*

I don't know for sure if your other sentence is grammatically incorrect, but it sure doesn't sound good. You could say:

> We will eat when I say so !

Which sounds a lot better, and seems to concern only the upcoming meal.

Comment: What you say sounds correct. "We will eat" somehow refers to the upcoming meal and "We eat" to all meals, as if the speaker is establishing a rule.